# Python script not running in SSIS package

Tags: python, ssis

I have python script running from SSIS package.
I am running python script in ".bat" file.
If I Execute SSIS package, it is running fine. Same package if I deploy and run/scheduled run it is failing with below error:

error: In Executing "D:/SSIS/PYTHON_SCRIPT/task.bat "D:/SSIS/PYTHON_SCRIPT/". The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0"

Any one have similar issue. Help me to solve this.

Comment: it will be better if you provide some more details. like what are the contents of script and bat file.

Comment: Hi Amit,

Python script have "print('Hello World')" saved this with test.py

bat file has:
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" "C:\Users\<XXXX>\test.py"

this bat file I have kept in SSIS Executable Process Task
under "Executable" and mentioned "WorkingDirectory"

Comment: Move test.py to the D:\SSIS\PYTHON_SCRIPT folder and edit the bat accordingly. Does that work? If so, it's a permissions issue. Well, assuming the user/process running SSIS can access D:\SSIS\PYTHON_SCRIPT folder but cannot access a User folder

Comment: Hi billinkc,
I have moved my python file to D:\ drive and ran SSIC job with my user, still I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Python Libraries are correctly configured and check Environment Variables as well